# iMac does not log to internet even though wifi connected

Tags: network, wifi, imac, internet

My MAcOs Sierra version 10-12-6  dont connect to internet anymore. I run diagnosis ISP failed, Internet failed, Server failed.

wifi (green light)
Wifi settings (green light)
Network settings (green light)

I have my laptop beside it and everything works fine.
I am desperate I navigated internet tried a lot of things without success.

Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Comment: tried this already:(

Comment: If you have a good network connection; then all that's left is your router.  Have you tried plugging in directly to the router via cable?  Does the problem go away?

Comment: No it is not the router, my Internet provider tested it

Comment: Did **you** test it by plugging in directly to the router?

Comment: No I guess I will have to but it is almost inaccessible from where it is located. But I will try

Comment: it seems that my internet was blocked and it is now solved. thank you